# Tagging people on blog entries and being able to access their profiles from tags

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm trying to create a blog posts where users are able to create challenges and tag other users. I succeeded in creating blog entries, I succeeded in adding tags on blog posts.

But I struggle with making so that clicking on tag would bring me to the user profile. I tried creating taxonomy called **users** and I specified *url alias*: `/user/*` Saddly if I clicked on tagged person, Im being brought to `..../taxonomy/term/4`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the [Mentions](https://www.drupal.org/project/mentions) module

> The Mentions module offers Twitter like functionality, recording all references to a user's username - using the **[@username]** or **[@#uid]** filter format - from various locations, providing a centralized page to track all mentions (via the Views module).

This module provides a configuration page, through that you can define the mentions pattern, and path (supports tokens)